# Qt Creator: community vs enterprise

Tags: qt, qt-creator

I [downloaded](https://download.qt.io/archive/qt/) and installed two versions of Qt, one is 5.9.4 and the other is 5.11.2. On operating system, one is shown with `Community` tag and the other with `Enterprise` tag. I wonder what the difference is:

[image: Start menu]

---

To clarify, I think I downloaded open-source version of Qt 5.11.2, but it is tagged as enterprise.

Comment: did you choose both times the opensource version?

Comment: @MrMaavin I downloaded on [this site](https://download.qt.io/archive/qt/). When downloading, I wasn't asked to choose.

Comment: I am facing the same issue... did you solved or clarified your doubt?

Comment: @shabang No, it is not solved unfortunately

Answer (score 1):

Qt Creator Commercial Features:

- You can use the following Qt Creator features if you have the appropriate Qt license.
- Performance Analyzer
- Browsing ISO 7000 Icons in the Design mode
- Developing for embedded devices
- Qt Application Manager integration

https://doc.qt.io/qtcreator/creator-commercial-overview.html