# How to move from Qt Enterprise to Qt Opensource without reinstalling Qt toolkit?

Tags: qt

I have installed Qt Creator recently but by mistake I picked a Qt enterprise trial. But I don't need Enterprise features of Qt. I want to write code for my github/show it to friends/for fun.

I have checked differences between community and enterprise editions:  [Qt Creator: community vs enterprise](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52828741/qt-creator-community-vs-enterprise/52881410) and I believe that it is quite possible to move to community edition without completely reinstalling Qt.

How do I move to Community edition from Enterprise trial edition without reinstalling qt toolkit?